# How to speed up a UITableView by storing the images in an ivar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ivar

I have a table view that is scrolling slowly. The data is from a server and is save to a NSArray. I've read that the slow scrolling is most likely because the images are loaded within  the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: code.

A solution might be to store the images in an ivar and then use them in the table. If that's the case how would I go about doing that? I haven't been able to find any sample code that does image caching and then uses it in UITable...

Comment: why u not use Asyncronious class reference for lazy loading images

Comment: Are you using the same image for each cell or different?

Comment: you should use gcd for this kind of business , images will be downloaded in the background and you should store them in your ivar at this point.

Comment: @Dave - a different image for every cell. each cell is a record of data that has a unique image, title, subtitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

[This sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrates a multi-stage approach to loading and displaying a UITableView. It begins by loading the relevant text from an RSS feed so the table can load as quickly as possible, and then downloads the images for each row asynchronously so the UI is more responsive.

Build Requirements: 
iOS SDK 5.0 or later

Runtime Requirements:
iOS 5.0 or later